# Prevent or move excel lock files

Tags: excel

We use a lot of excel files as resources.   When you open an excel file - it creates the ~$file as a lock file in the same directory as the other file.  Which then stops our code compiling - because tools notice it and pick it up.

On a case by case basis - eg git - it is usually possible to exclude those files - but it would be much better if we could stop them occurring - and best if we could say "always create them in THIS other directory".

Is any of that possible?

Comment: Stupid question: Can you not just modify the tool to ignore files of that type? If not, this is out of my realm of expertise. Maybe do some research on Microsoft's website. If none of these are acceptable solutions, you may just want to use other database tools such as SQL.

Comment: a) there are lots of tools ... source controls, ides, build tools, analysis tools - so we have to modify each one...  and b) some of them I don't know how (that's a separate stackoverflow question ;))